# The probability of occurence of $A$ is $\frac{2}{9}$ and of $B$ is $\frac{5}{9}$. Find the probability of occurence of only one of the events

Tags: probability

The probability of occurence of $A$ is $\frac{2}{9}$ and of $B$ is $\frac{5}{9}$. Find the probability of occurence of only one of the events. ($A$ and $B$ are two independent events)

My solution goes like this:

> If $P(A)=\frac{2}{9}$ and $P(B)=\frac{5}{9}$. Also $P(A\cup B) $ denotes the probability of occurence of $A$ or $B$ .So, $P(A\cup B)=1-P(\overline{A})P(\overline{B})=\frac{53}{81}$.

However, if we do this in the following way:

> If $P(A)=\frac{2}{9}$ and $P(B)=\frac{5}{9}$. Also $P(A\cap \overline {B})$  denotes probability of occurence of $A$ and $\overline {B}$. Similarly, $P(\overline {A}\cap B)$ denotes  probability of occurence of $B$ and $\overline {A}$. So, $P(\overline {A}\cap B)=P(\overline{A})P(B)=\frac{35}{81}$ and   $P(\overline {B}\cap A)=P(\overline{B})P(A)=\frac{8}{81}$. So the required probability is $\frac{43}{81}$.

Which method is valid? Why is the other one not valid? Does $P(A\cup B)$ which means probability of occurence of "either $A$ or $B$ " not equivalent to probability of occurence of "only one of the two events $A$ and $B$ "? If they are  not equivalent , why is it so?Where is the problem occuring?  I am not quite getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "or" in set union is **inclusive**. If both $A$ and $B$ occur, then $A \cup B$ has indeed occurred; hence, $A \cup B$ does not correctly describe the phenomenon in the problem statement. The second solution is correct, because it explores the two distinct cases of "$A$ occurring without $B$" and "$B$ occurring without $A$," which is the precise collection of ways that one event can occur without the other.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitional answer uses what I call a "line diagram"

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(A\cap B) = \frac29\frac59=\frac{10}{81}$, put in the **middle** of the line diagram

$\boxed{P(\text {only A )}}\boxed{P(A\cap B=\frac{10}{81}}\boxed{P(\text {only B )}}$

Thus P(only A ) + P(only B) $= (\frac 29 - \frac{10}{81} + \frac 59 - \frac{10}{81})$

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you are looking for the symmetric difference of A and B. That is the event where either A occurs but not B or B but not A. In terms of a set one can write this as
$$A\bigtriangleup B:= (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B).$$ You might see, this is your second method. Maybe draw a Venn-Diagram to see why this holds.

However, it is somewhat easier to use the expression after the second "=" above. Since $A$ and $B$ are independent $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=10/81$. Further $$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B).$$ From that you gain $$\mathbb P(A\bigtriangleup B)=\mathbb P(A\cup B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-2\mathbb P(A\cap B).$$ (which is the line diagram approach from another answer).